# Cube containing cubes

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, packing-problem

What's the size of smallest cube containing 5 unit cubes? Is there a way to generalize result for 5?

I'm more interested in proving minimality, than actaully calculating the size, though.

Comment: Can't think of anything smaller than $2\times 2\times 2$...

Comment: @J.M Any ideas to prove minimality? How about 7 or 9 cubes?

Comment: Not really. My only thought was finding the smallest cube larger than the given number of unit cubes...

Answer (score 5):

The generalization may still be an open problem. See Erich Friedman's [Cubes in Cubes](https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/cubincub/).

"For all other values of n < 34, the trivial packing is the best known."

Comment: "best known" = proven minimal?

Comment: No, he should have explicitly wrote that if that's what was intended.